# Is there a standard way for setting a site specific value at install time for Perl scripts?

Tags: perl, installation, configuration-files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Separating configuration data and script logic in Perl scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381508/separating-configuration-data-and-script-logic-in-perl-scripts)

[StevedoreUtil.pm](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~cwhii/stevedore/trunk/annotate/11/stevedore/src/server/StevedoreUtil.pm) sets a value used for email addresses:

```
my $STEVE_SITE_EMAIL_DOMAIN = "mydomain.net";
```

Unfortunately, this should not be hard coded in the Perl script. Is there a standard way to set a value like this once when the application is first installed?

See [Stevedore Project](https://launchpad.net/stevedore) on [launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/) and the [Stevedore Web Site](http://stevedore.110mb.com/) for the context of [StevedoreUtil.pm](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~cwhii/stevedore/trunk/annotate/11/stevedore/src/server/StevedoreUtil.pm).

Comment: No, of course configuration should not be hard-coded in the script. Configuration variables should live in configuration files. I am not sure if you are just trying to publicize your stuff with this post, but, FYI, `$#ARGV+1 == 2` is better written as `@ARGV == 2`.

Comment: @Ether how does that address the issue of setting the value at install time. The question is also asking for a standard way rather than say the faster execution time, the easiest to code or the easiest to maintain.

Comment: W.Holeman: your installer could generate a config file, or insert values into an existing one.  That question does cover the various classic implementations, including the tradeoffs of each.

Answer (score 1):

Both `ExtUtils::MakeMaker` and `Module::Build` have facilities for running scripts with the `*.PL` extension to create new files at installation time. Some distributions include files with names like `Foo.pm.PL` to create files like `Foo.pm`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the value of `$Config{perladmin}` out of the `Config` module has something that works for Perl proper and is determined at build time:

```
% perl -V:perladmin
perladmin='tchrist@chthon.perl.com';
```

However, I’m unaware of any sort of convention for supporting that sort of notion for a given module/class/file. It’s hard enough getting `UNIVERSAL->VERSION()` support.

Still, there may be something to your idea. I’d be somewhat surprised if it hadn’t already been discussed elsewhere. A really quick check on the documentation for the various module build mechanisms didn’t turn up anything obvious.